# Change function to use as onchange event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following `javascript` function for listbox organization:

```
$("#organization").change(function(e) {
//function updateOrganization() {
    organization = $("#organization").val();
    indicator = $("#indicators").val();
    funcid = "fill_chart_average_score";

    //console.log('changed'); 
    $.getJSON('functions/getfunctions.php', {
        "organization":organization,
        "indicator":indicator,
        "funcid":funcid},

    function(dataChart) {

            var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartaveragescore", {
            "theme": "light",
            "type": "serial",
            "startDuration": 1,
            "dataProvider": dataChart,
            "rotate": false,
            "categoryField": "organisatie",
              "valueAxes": [ {
                "gridColor": "#FFFFF",
                "gridAlpha": 0.2,
                "dashLength": 0
              } ],
              "gridAboveGraphs": true,
              "startDuration": 1,
              "graphs": [ {
                "balloonText": "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
                "fillColorsField": "fillcolor", //Dit veld heb ik meegegeven vanuit SQL functie en bevat de HEX kleurcodes BD
                "fillAlphas": 0.8,
                "lineAlpha": 0.2,
                "type": "column",
                "valueField": "score"
              } ],
              "chartCursor": {
                "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
                "cursorAlpha": 0,
                "zoomable": false
              },
              "categoryAxis": {
                "gridPosition": "start",
                "gridAlpha": 0,
                "tickPosition": "start",
                "tickLength": 20
              },
              "export": {
                "enabled": true
              }

        },0);

    $('.chart-input').off().on('input change',function() {
        var property = jQuery(this).data('property');
        var target = chart;
        chart.startDuration = 0;

        });
    });
});
```

This works great, but what i want now is to make a function not based on `$("#organization").change(function(e)` but just make a function like `function updateOrganization()` and call this function in an `onchange` within the `html` element. When i change the `$("#organization").change(function(e)` with `function updateOrganization()` the function doesn't work anymore.

I'm a starting `javascript` learner :).

Comment: Just try `$("#organization").change(updateOrganization);`

Comment: Is there a reason you want to amend this code to work from an event attribute? That would be considered a step backwards in terms of how the code should be structured.

Comment: Hi Rory, well, I want to be able to call 2 functions at the `onchange` event for the listbox organization. thats the reason.

Comment: Rory, I already got the issue: i got a `);` too many at the end of the function when I changed it to `function updateOrganization()`. Now it does work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to call function on change of dropdown and you want to do it with onchange event of select tag. [This](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onchange) might help you.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare your function outside the block. Something like:

```
function updateOrganization() {
    organization = $("#organization").val();
    indicator = $("#indicators").val();
    funcid = "fill_chart_average_score";

    // ...
}
```

and then use it as:

```
$("#organization").change(updateOrganization);
```

Comment: And can I also call two functions within the `$("#organization").change(updateOrganization);`?